Call to a member function isSaleable error
After I updated my Magento I got this error and it caused some issues like Add to cart etc.
An error message is:

#130 {main} {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Call to a member function isSaleable() on null at
/chroot/home/ab140e0b/6e29c5a329.nxcli.io/html/app/code/KraftMedia/GroupedProduct/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml:7)"}
[]

The code the error is referring to:
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $viewModel->canShowAddToCart($_product)) :?>
<div class="box-tocart">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()) :?>
        <div class="field qty">
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="number"
                name="qty"
                id="qty"
                min="0"
                value="<?= $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Qty')) ?>"
                class="input-text qty"
                data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

This module stops customers from buying grouped products if 1 of the products is out of stock.
Is this possible to this in Magento out of box now, or do we need to fix this error? And do anyone know how to fix this issue?

Can you please tell me current version of magento ?
